terragrunt - Only one level of includes is allowed
is there a limitation on terragrunt that it can only have only one level of includes.
├── live
│   └── env
│       ├── dev
│       │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│       ├── qa
│       └── terragrunt.hcl
└── terragrunt.hcl

I have folder structure as mentioned above.
at each level I have some inputs defined which I using in child.  however, while trying to do so I am getting error.
live/terragrunt.hcl
inputs = {
  account = "root"
}

live/env/terragrunt.hcl
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}


inputs = {
  env = "dev"
}

live/env/dev/terragrunt.hcl
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

terraform {
  source = "../../../module/"
}
inputs = {
  name = "gaurang"
}

Error

ERRO[0000] /test_terragrunt/live/env/dev/terragrunt.hcl includes
/test_terragrunt/live/env/terragrunt.hcl, which itself includes
/test_terragrunt/live/env/terragrunt.hcl. Only one level of includes
is allowed.
ERRO[0000] Unable to determine underlying exit code, so
Terragrunt will exit with error code 1

And If I remove includes from live/env it doesn't merge the input from parent folder (i.e. live/terragrunt.hcl).

I solved it my using multiple includes in my child terragurnt.
include "env" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders("terragrunt.hcl")
}

include "account" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders("../terragrunt.hcl")
}

terraform {
  source = "../../../module/"
}
inputs = {
  name = "gaurang"
}

